Optimizing Disk Performance - IOPS/Throughput
I've got a VM used for SQL, and it's being suggested that splitting temp-DB, transaction logs, master, etc. onto separate physical disks will boost performance.
This VM is in a datacenter (all flash storage, raid50). Diagnostics for our VM reads peak IOPS is 1772 and 95th Percentile IOPS is 373. The avg. Latency is < .25ms (peak 2ms), and peak throughput was 1.07 GB/s. Datacenter is saying that the array our storage is sitting on has around 60,000 IOPS available with great throughput and low latency and suggest that even if drives were moved to separate datastores (which may not even be feasible), it wouldn't get any faster than we're already experiencing.
I'm fairly new to the IOPS/throughput/datacenter metrics, so could anyone corroborate this to be true given the metrics we're currently getting?

I believe Windows caps the disk queue length to 5 outstanding I/O operations. So create a separate virtual hard drive, so that Windows can queue another 5 on a pagefile driver, another 5 on a tempdb drive, another 5 on a transaction log drive.

A workload peaking at 1800 IOPS is not likely to hit bottlenecks on an all flash array capable of 60000 IOPS.  Not impossible, but it can service IOs so fast certain tuning is no longer essential for performance.
An ideal storage exercise would involve testing to a bottleneck. Most people cannot summon tens of thousand of IOPS from test workloads on demand, which implies synthetic IO testing tools.  DiskSpd, or  fio on Linux and POSIX. Build a test host with the same OS and storage layout.  Push it to 50000 IOPS and beyond with IO patterns similar to what the DB engine would do, like an OLTP scenario.
Look at the percentiles of latency in particular, 99th or more nines.  Average alone will not describe the statistical distribution.
And test again, but with data, logs, and temp on separate logical disks. If your statement about not being faster were true, there would not be a significant difference in latency. However, at a high level of IOPS, there could be limits in the number of concurrent IOs on a given disk and file system. Resulting in latency earlier than you would expect just given the raw performance possible of the physical disk.
Separating data log and temp might have operational advantages. More flexible layout for other storage systems.  In some clouds, each disk has specific performance quotas, and you get a fast SSD local disk. When they already are files on different volumes, its straightforward to have each backed by a different type of disk.
Up to you whether separate volumes are worth implementing. Maybe can wait until the next OS upgrade or storage migration results in new storage for other reasons.  Maybe never bother, doesn't matter based on your capacity planning.
